# How does a parent address their child's teacher or principal?

Tags: grammar, politeness, honorifics

Would the honorific さま (-sama) surfice when addressing a teacher or principal? I'm uncertain if a parent would use 先生 (sensei) or こうちょうせんせい (kōchōsensei) as it's not *their* teacher, but their child's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the person is principal, it's 校長先生{こうちょうせんせい}. Otherwise, you use *Last Name*+先生. The rule is that you call them as your child would call them.

FYI: In kindergarten (幼稚園{ようちえん} or 保育園{ほいくえん}), the head of school is 園長{えんちょう}先生.